# Ruby - NoMethodError (undefined method for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, null, nomethoderror

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.  My `ActiveRecord` query is returning `nil` which I think is causing `NoMethodError` to be raised.

Here's what I have:

```
@number_exclude_list = ["1234567890", "2223334545"] 
@available_number = UserNumber.where.not(:user_num => @number_exclude_list)
```

Which returns an empty set of rows:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

So, then I have:

```
if (@available_number.empty?)
   inform_user_empty
else
   do_my_other_function
```

But, I get:

```
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'inform_user_empty' for nil:NilClass)`
```

I have tried: `@available_number.blank?` and `` `@available_number.nil? ``

And I still get the same `NoMethodError`.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe, this not the proper place `inform_user_empty` for the exception: because you have called to `self.inform_user_empty`, is the `self` `nil`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, but, the `inform_user_empty` function is in the `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: Yes, but your error says: `undefined method 'inform_user_empty' for nil:NilClass`, in other words this is leaded by call to `nil.inform_user_empty` but since `inform_user_empty` function is in the `application_controller.rb`. It can't be. replace `inform_user_empty` to `self.inform_user_empty`. insert `p self` before, and try again

Comment: Try @available_number.present?

Answer (score 2):

The exception text `NoMethodError (undefined method 'inform_user_empty' for nil:NilClass)` says that is was a call to instance method `#inform_user_empty` of the `nil` class'es instance, and since `nil` has no instance method [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) interpreter throwed that exception. I see the two main reason for it:

1. `self` keyword variable has `nil` value, I believe not in the reason, because you do a call from a controller, as you've said `ApplicationController`. To make sure that `self` isn't `nil`, change the code to the following one:

   ```
   if @available_number.empty?
      p self
      self.inform_user_empty
   ```

   rerun the action, and look at the result.
2. The exception has been thrown from another place. So you have to specify the full trace log in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below line in your console:

```
@available_number = UserNumber.where.not(:user_num => @number_exclude_list)
```

it returns an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)` since it is not the way to check `NOT IN` condition in Rails activerecord.

Replace it with:

```
User.where('user_num NOT IN (?)',@number_exclude_list)
```

and then do:

```
if @available_number == nil
   inform_user_empty
else
   do_my_other_function
end
```

Hoep that will resolve the issue. Please let me know if it really helped you.